# Swift 3 upgrade error --Execute bad code

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift3

I am new to swift, upgraded my code to swift 3.

Swift 2.3 code follows:

```
func sectionTite() {
        let keyArray:NSArray  = self.messageDictionary.allKeys
        let sortedArray = keyArray.sortedArrayUsingComparator { (dateString1: AnyObject, dateString2: AnyObject) -> NSComparisonResult in
            let d1:NSDate = NSDate.dateFromString(dateString1 as! String, fromFormat: NSDate.DateFormat.KYYYY_MM_DD)
            let d2: NSDate = NSDate.dateFromString(dateString2 as! String, fromFormat: NSDate.DateFormat.KYYYY_MM_DD)
            return (d1 ).compare(d2 )
        }
        self.sectionArray = sortedArray
    }
```

Swift 3.0

```
func sectionTite() {
        let keyArray:NSArray  = self.messageDictionary.allKeys as NSArray
        let sortedArray = keyArray.sortedArray (comparator: { (dateString1: AnyObject, dateString2: AnyObject) -> ComparisonResult in
            let d1:Date = Date.dateFromString(dateString1 as! NSString , fromFormat: Date.DateFormat.KYYYY_MM_DD as NSString)
            print(d1)
            let d2: Date = Date.dateFromString(dateString2 as! NSString, fromFormat: Date.DateFormat.KYYYY_MM_DD as NSString)
            return (d1 ).compare(d2 )
        } as! (Any, Any) -> ComparisonResult)
        self.sectionArray = sortedArray as NSArray
    }
```

The above code crashed states EXC_breakpoint (code1,subcode...), its doesnt states the reason for crash. keyArray consists of a date item.Below code creating problem.

```
let keyArray:NSArray  = self.messageDictionary.allKeys as NSArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use native swift type `Array` and `Dictionary` instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. So declare your `sectionArray` as `[String]` instead of `NSArray`

```
var sectionArray = [String]()
```

Now sort your dictionary keys like this way.

```
if let dic = self.messageDictionary as? [String:Any] {
    let keys = Array(dic.keys) as [String]
    let dateForamatter = DateFormatter()
    dateForamatter.dateFormat = Date.DateFormat.KYYYY_MM_DD //Set Your dateFormat
    self.sectionArray = keys.sorted(by: { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
        let date1 = dateForamatter.date(from: str1)! //I have force wrapped
        let date2 = dateForamatter.date(from: str2)!
        return date1 < date2
    })
}
```

Comment: It states an error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguemets", also i need to change lot in the class
 self.sectionArray = keys.sorted(by: { (str1, str2) -> Bool in 
This line throws an exception.

Comment: @SinsonAntony have you added same code can you edit your question with your try because this code is perfectly build in my Xcode 8, Swift 3 without any error.

Comment: @SinsonAntony Can you show me the screen shot with error that you are currently getting with my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let keyArray:NSArray  = self.messageDictionary.allKeys as NSArray
        let dateForamatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateForamatter.dateFormat = Date.DateFormat.KYYYY_MM_DD //Set Your dateFormat
                    self.sectionArray = keyArray.sorted(by: { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
                        let date1 = dateForamatter.date(from: str1 as! String)! 
                        let date2 = dateForamatter.date(from: str2 as! String)!
                        return date1 < date2
                    }) as NSArray

        self.sectionArray = keyArray as NSArray
    }
```